# I relate two or more entities

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> My prefix will lay you to rest
>   And is also a legitimate prefix
>   My infix may be pretence
>   And is a prefix of my suffix
>
> My suffix can be performed
>   It may relate to moving
>   I relate two or more entities;
>   Objects or even the living

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are an:

> **INTERACTION**

*My prefix will lay you to rest*
*And is also a legitimate prefix*

> The word '**INTER**' means 'bury' or '*lay to rest*'. It is also a prefix meaning 'between' as in 'international' ('between nations'), for example.

*My infix may be pretence*
*And is a prefix of my suffix*

> An '**ACT**' *may be a pretence*, a facade. It is also the first part of the suffix (see below)...

*My suffix can be performed*
*It may relate to moving*

> An '**ACTION**' is something that *can be performed* (e.g. a movement).

*I relate two or more entities;*
*Objects or even the living*

> Altogether, these parts make **INTERACTION** - a word which suggests a relationship between *two or more entities*, each of which has an effect on the other(s). This could (e.g.) be social interaction (conversation and mingling) or the interaction of an animal with its surroundings...